# Firebase with retrofit return 401 error fcm

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am newbie with fcm and now I am trying to build an android application and using fcm to send message to topic subscriptions but I always get 401 error and searched for this error more and more but I can't solve this problem. this is my code:
**Constants.kt**

```
class Constants {
    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com"
        const val SERVER_KEY = "#############-##################CCSnRLNd_wFrm0H5###########LfzT1KqV1###########"
        const val CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json"
    }
}
```

**NotificationApi.kt**

```
interface NotificationApi {
    @Headers("Authorization: key = ${Constants.SERVER_KEY}, " +
            "Content-Type: ${Constants.CONTENT_TYPE}")
    @POST("fcm/send")
    suspend fun postNotification(
        @Body notification:PushNotification
    ) : Response<ResponseBody>
}
```

**NotificationData.kt**

```
data class NotificationData(val title:String,val msg:String) {}
```

**PushNotification.kt**

```
data class PushNotification (val data: NotificationData, val to:String) {}
```

**RetrofitInstance.kt**

```
class RetrofitInstance {
    companion object {
        private val retrofit by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

        val api by lazy {
            retrofit.create(NotificationApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**Sending.kt**

```
class Sending {
    fun sendNotification(notification:PushNotification) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(notification)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("Sending Notification","suc Response : ${Gson().toJson(response)}")
            } else {
                Log.e("Sending Notification","fail Response : ${response.code()}\n${response.body()}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Error Sending",e.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

so what is error with my code I am sure with my server key but I don't know what is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

I found my server key from my firebase console
[as this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOgOl.png)